# Import schema file into SQL server express database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema, ssms

I am trying to setup the database for an openfire install, but I cant seem to figure out how to import database schema into a database I had just created in SQL Server Management Studio. I tried using the import data tool and then loaded the file into the write query screen and it is comming back with errors.

I have a feeling that isnt how to do it though.

If I go to tasks>Generate scripts, and then choose the database it says that their are no scritable objects in the database.

I somehow need to find a way to run the database schema into my newly created database. The instructions from openfire seem easy but it requires the console and I am not sure how to access that. I am a beginner when it comes to SQL server.

These are the instructions:

```
Setup Instructions

Make sure that you are using MySQL 4.1.18 or later (5.x recommended) ¹.
Create a database for the Openfire tables:
mysqladmin create [databaseName]
(note: "databaseName" can be something like 'openfire')
Import the schema file from the resources/database directory of the installation folder:
Unix/Linux: cat openfire_mysql.sql | mysql [databaseName]; 
Windows: type openfire_mysql.sql | mysql [databaseName];
Start the Openfire setup tool, and use the appropriate JDBC connection settings.
¹ Character fields larger than 255 are not supported by versions prior to MySQL 4.1.18. If you cannot upgrade MySQL to the latest version, you will then need to change the database scripts. In particular, replace VARCHAR(1024) with VARCHAR(255) in the resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql script.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about OpenFire ala Ignite RealTime you need to follow the instruction for Microsoft SQL Server (not MySQL).

The [reference page](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html#sqlserver) instructions for Microsoft SQL Server has the following

SQL Server

JDBC Drivers
Openfire includes the Free TDS JDBC driver, which is the recommended way to connect to SQL Server databases. To connect to SQL Server, simply use the following values in the Openfire web-based setup tool:

driver -- net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
server -- jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[host-name]:[port-number]/[database-name];appName=jive
where [host-name] is the host name or IP address of your database server, and [port-number] is the port that SQLServer is listening on (normally 1433) and [database-name] is the name of the database (this parameter is optional).

Setup Instructions

Create a new database using Enterprise Manager if you do not already have a database you want to use. You may wish to name the database "openfire".

Create a user to access the database if you do not already have one you'd like to use. Consider making the default database for the user be the one you created in step 1.

Open the Query Analyser and connect to the server.

Select the database you want to use for Openfire from the DB drop down (the one you created in step 1 if you're using a new database).

Open the openfire_sqlserver.sql file.

Press F5 to run the script. The script will run and create the necessary tables.

Proceed to the Openfire setup tool and use the appropriate JDBC settings when prompted.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Been a long day. Thank you.